# Eigenvalues of Sturm–Liouville operator

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues, sturm-liouville-theory

Can we calculate the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the following operator in $W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})$?

$$-\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^2x}\right)y''-\frac{2}{\cosh^4x}y=\lambda y.$$

Comment: Yes, if "we" is maple or mathematica. It involves Mathieu functions apparently

Answer (score 7):

For me, the first (and usually only) attempt with such Sturm-Liouville equations is to rewrite them as Schrodinger equations, using [this transformation.](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Liouville_normal_form)

If I got everything right, ... **EDIT:** but I didn't in the first attempt, as hyh pointed out. The correct transformed equation is
$$
-u'' + V(t)u = \lambda u , \quad\quad V(t) =\frac{-t^2-6}{4(t^2+1)^2} ;
$$
the variables are related to the old ones by $t=\sinh x$, $u=\sqrt{\cosh x} y$.

This is a similar, but slightly more subtle situation than with my original incorrect potential. We now have $V=-1/(4t^2)-1/t^4+O(t^{-6})$. What is clear is that we have purely absolutely continuous spectrum of multiplicity $2$ on $\sigma_{ac}=[0,\infty)$. Below $\lambda =0$, we have purely discrete spectrum.

The question of whether we have finitely or infinitely many eigenvalues below zero is probably answerable, but seems a bit tricky. The potential $W=-1/(4t^2)$ would lead to finite discrete spectrum, but is exactly the borderline case in the sense that $W=-c/t^2$ for $c>1/4$ would give infinitely many eigenvalues.

**EDIT 2:** I'm reasonably confident now that there are only finitely many eigenvalues, though to show it properly would probably require some work. We could try to argue as follows: on the interval $2^n\le t\le 2^{n+1}$, we can bound $V$ from below by $-c_n/t^2$, $c_n=1/4+2^{-2n}$. For this modified potential, the solutions at $\lambda =0$ look like $t^{1/2}t^{i2^{-n}}=t^{1/2}e^{i2^{-n}\log t}$ (the equation for the modified potential is an Euler equation and can be solved explicitly). So the phase increases by $\approx n2^{-n}$ on the interval under consideration. Since this is summable, we expect (real valued) solutions to have only finitely many zeros, and then the claim follows from oscillation theory (see the comments).

Third and (let's hope) final **EDIT:** There are indeed only finitely many eigenvalues. A much better argument (than the previous paragraph) is given by Giorgio in the comments.

Comment: I don't know if my last paragraph can perhaps be confusing, so just to clarify: I'm referring to results from the spectral theory of such operators here, I'm not saying that any of this is immediately obvious.

Comment: How do you prove that the eigenvalues below $-1/4$ are infinetely many?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: The standard proof is by oscillation theory, by solving the (Euler) equation $-y''-(c/x^2)y=0$ and checking whether or not the solution has infinitely many zeros (it switches at $c=1/4$).

Comment: Let me check what I have understood. By comparison with $-D^2-1/(4t^2)$ you show that every solution of $-u''-(V+1/4)u=0$ oscillates infinitely many times near infinity. If correct, why this gives infinitely many eigenvalues?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: It's based on what is called *oscillation theory*, it's not obvious. What I'm using here is (roughly): if a solution of $-u''+Vu=Eu$ has $N$ zeros, then there are $N$ eigenvalues below $E$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Does this help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_theory#Connection_with_spectral_theory (you can certainly find much better presentations if you search around a little, though)

Comment: Many thanks, this is what I was missing.

Comment: $V(t)=\frac{-t^2-6}{4(t^2+1)^2}$ not $V(t)=\frac{-t^2-6}{4(t^2+1)}$

Comment: @hyh: You are right, see my edited answer for the actual situation.

Comment: @ChristianRemling $u''+1(4x^2)u'+1/(x^4)u=0$ with $x=e^t$ becomes $u_{tt}-u_t+1/4 u+e^{-2t}u=0$ and $u=ye^{t/2}$ gives $y_{tt}+e^{-2t}y=0$. All solutions of $y_{tt}+a(t)y=0$ with $\int_a^\infty t|a(t)| <\infty$ behave like straight lines at $\infty$ and cannot oscillate. This should imply that there is a bound for the number of zeros of the original equation with $V$ and then, by what you explained to me, that the eigenvalues are finitely many.

Comment: It is just a misprint, the rest should be corrrect

Comment: @ChristianRemling The first equation is $u''+1/(4x^2)u+1/(x^4)u=0$ (and I wrote erroneously $u'$). This transforms into $u_{tt}-u_t+1/4 u+e^{-2t}u=0$ under $x=e^t$ and this last into $y_{tt}+e^{-2t}y=0$ under $u=ye^{t/2}$. I did two transformations.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I get it now. This is very nice and much cleaner than my sketch above. (At the end, we can also argue by comparing $e^{-2t}<1/(4t^2)$ one more time.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling I did not notice your second edit, strange! Ah true, comparison with $1/4t^2$ again simplifies an argument that I left unexplained.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I now realize that none of this was necessary, we can simply see from the original equation (as given by the OP), that the $\lambda=0$ solutions have only finitely many zeros (using your criterion, for example)...

Comment: @ChristianRemling That is true, indeed. After a big detour and changes of variables, this point is more clear from the original equation.